# My URL is not redirct properly in angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm very new in this and I have just add new component using command. The component is created successfully.

app.module.ts

```
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
   AppComponent,    
   LoginComponent    
 ],
 imports: [
   FormsModule,
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule ,
   RouterModule   
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
```

Then in app-routing.module.ts

```
 import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

  const routes: Routes = [  
       { path: 'login' , component:LoginComponent}
  ];

  @NgModule({
  imports: [
     CommonModule , RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  declarations: []
  })
```

Then I have add in login.module.ts

```
 import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

 declarations: [LoginComponent]
```

Then I have set login.routing.module.ts

```
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
const routes: Routes = [
   { path:'' , component:LoginComponent }
];
```

I have set Login link in app.component.html

```
<a href="/login">Login</a>
```

When I run my app usign npm start commnd and open browser with localhost:4200
it will show link properly but when I clicked on that page just reload not redirect on login page.

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? And why do you declare LoginComponent twice, once in app module and once in LoginModule? And the same routing twice?

Comment: No it's a same page and I have also remove from LoginModule but it has not change any thing.

Comment: I have also see that in brower -> Network to see that status of my request I found that it shows `Others` in initiator. So is there any issue of that ? @David

Comment: Not sure. Can you create a stackblitz example showing your issue?

Comment: Not sure. Can you create a stackblitz example showing your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change

```
<a href="/login">Login</a>
```

to this

```
<a routerLink="/login">Login</a>
```

See also [Routing & Navigation - Router Links](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links)

Answer (score 1):

You just add this in your `app.module.js` in `import`.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path:'login', component:LoginComponent}
])
```

and make sure your `app.html` has `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

In your `app-routing.module` please update `path` like this.

```
 { path:'login' , loadChildren:'./login/login.module#LoginModule'}
```